# is it possible to extend activity class and PreferenceActivity class at the same time

Tags: vb.net, preferenceactivity

I want to have my main class for creating activity for 2 different flags.

1) One with relative layout Textview and images for which I am extending my class as

```
public class Abcd extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, _  
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, ViewFactory{
```

2) secondly with linear layout as to have a textview imageview and list.

now for the second case I want to use preferencescreen instead of list, for which I have to extend my activity from PreferenceActivity .

Need your suggestion if I can do so.

Thanks
Vani

Answer (score 0):

VB does not support it, neither does C#.

This is referred to as [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) and there's plenty of information available if you search for that word.

Generally you would want polymorphism because you want to attach two types of behavior to the class - you can achieve this just as easily by using [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) - again there is plenty of advice available if you search for that term.

Comment: Thanks for the Response Greg. I am using this in Android UI. Any suggestion for it.

Comment: @Vani as mentioned you can use composition over inheritance.